# Отключение https в скрипте установки nextcloud

Tags: nginx, https, nextcloud

Нашел скрипт по автоматической установке Nextcloud на Debian, однако, не могу его модифицировать таким образом, что бы исключить использование https.
Ссылка на мануал со скриптом: https://riegers.in/install-nextcloud-18-using-one-script-only/
Сам скрипт: https://privat.c-rieger.de/s/ZqHd5rW7NLRgwHR/download
Пробовал вручную комментировать строки в конфигурации nginx, но это приводило к ошибкам установки. 
Буду признателен, если подскажете, как следует доработать этот скрипт таким образом, что бы он отрабатывал полностью, но при этом, не подключал https. Своих умений, к сожалению, для этого не достаточно.

Comment: на докере развери, делов на 1 минуту, и не надо ничего делать, на дворе 2020 год

Comment: да, а еще можно использовать снап убунты, или купить яндекс.диск и не париться.